# How do I convert a tuple of tuples to a one-dimensional list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

I have a tuple of tuples - for example:

```
tupleOfTuples = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5,))
```

I want to convert this into a flat, one-dimensional list of all the elements in order:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I've been trying to accomplish this with list comprehension. But I can't seem to figure it out. I was able to accomplish it with a for-each loop:

```
myList = []
for tuple in tupleOfTuples:
   myList = myList + list(tuple)
```

But I feel like there must be a way to do this with a list comprehension.

A simple `[list(tuple) for tuple in tupleOfTuples]` just gives you a list of lists, instead of individual elements. I thought I could perhaps build on this by using the unpacking operator to then unpack the list, like so:

```
[*list(tuple) for tuple in tupleOfTuples]
```

or

```
[*(list(tuple)) for tuple in tupleOfTuples]
```

... but that didn't work. Any ideas? Or should I just stick to the loop?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

it's typically referred to as flattening a nested structure.

```
>>> tupleOfTuples = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5,))
>>> [element for tupl in tupleOfTuples for element in tupl]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Just to demonstrate efficiency:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> it = lambda: list(chain(*tupleOfTuples))
>>> timeit.timeit(it)
2.1475738355700913
>>> lc = lambda: [element for tupl in tupleOfTuples for element in tupl]
>>> timeit.timeit(lc)
1.5745135182887857
```

**ETA**: Please don't use `tuple` as a variable name, it shadows built-in.

Comment: thanks... do you mind giving i and j more meaningful names so I can more easily follow this logic?

Comment: @SilentGhost - thanks! is this widely accepted? I find it harder to understand at first glance than the longer loop... but if programmers recognize the pattern then I would use it

Comment: @froadie: it's an idiomatic way of flattening a shallow list.

Comment: I wondered how it looks for longer lists, ie `tupleOfTuples=tuple(zip(range(0,100,2), range(1,100,2)))` -- in that case, `chain` is slightly faster than the LC (and Fabian's `chain.from_iterable` is the fastest)

Comment: @THC4k: Not on my machine, here fastest one is `list(chain.from_iterable(tupleOfTuples))`. Fabians, solution is as slow as mine or even slower.

Comment: @SilentGhost yeah you're right, i actually tested that same code, not Fabians LC.

Comment: What about `numpy.array(tupleOfTuples).flatten()` ? After making it a list

Comment: Struggling to understand how it works. Is there any resource you can recommend with a step-by-step explanation of it?

Answer (score 46):

Just use `sum` if you don't have a lot of tuples.

```
>>> tupleOfTuples = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5,))
>>> sum(tupleOfTuples, ())
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> list(sum(tupleOfTuples, ())) # if you really need a list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you do have a lot of tuples, use [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3204267/224671) or [`chain.from_iterable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3204409/224671) to prevent the quadratic behavior of `sum`.

---

### Micro-benchmarks:

- Python 2.6

  - Long tuple of short tuples

    ```
    $ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, 2), )*500' '[element for tupl in tot for element in tupl]'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 134 usec per loop
    $ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, 2), )*500' 'list(sum(tot, ()))'
    1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 msec per loop
    $ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, 2), )*500; from itertools import chain; ci = chain.from_iterable' 'list(ci(tot))'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 60.1 usec per loop
    $ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, 2), )*500; from itertools import chain' 'list(chain(*tot))'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 64.8 usec per loop
    ```
  - Short tuple of long tuples

    ```
    $ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, )*500, (2, )*500)' '[element for tupl in tot for element in tupl]'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 65.6 usec per loop
    $ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, )*500, (2, )*500)' 'list(sum(tot, ()))'
    100000 loops, best of 3: 16.9 usec per loop
    $ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, )*500, (2, )*500); from itertools import chain; ci = chain.from_iterable' 'list(ci(tot))'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 25.8 usec per loop
    $ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, )*500, (2, )*500); from itertools import chain' 'list(chain(*tot))'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 26.5 usec per loop
    ```
- Python 3.1

  - Long tuple of short tuples

    ```
    $ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, 2), )*500' '[element for tupl in tot for element in tupl]'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 121 usec per loop
    $ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, 2), )*500' 'list(sum(tot, ()))'
    1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 msec per loop
    $ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, 2), )*500; from itertools import chain; ci = chain.from_iterable' 'list(ci(tot))'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 59.5 usec per loop
    $ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, 2), )*500; from itertools import chain' 'list(chain(*tot))'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 63.2 usec per loop
    ```
  - Short tuple of long tuples

    ```
    $ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, )*500, (2, )*500)' '[element for tupl in tot for element in tupl]'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 66.1 usec per loop
    $ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, )*500, (2, )*500)' 'list(sum(tot, ()))'
    100000 loops, best of 3: 16.3 usec per loop
    $ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, )*500, (2, )*500); from itertools import chain; ci = chain.from_iterable' 'list(ci(tot))'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 25.4 usec per loop
    $ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'tot = ((1, )*500, (2, )*500); from itertools import chain' 'list(chain(*tot))'
    10000 loops, best of 3: 25.6 usec per loop
    ```

Observation:

- `sum` is faster if the outer tuple is short.
- `list(chain.from_iterable(x))` is faster if the outer tuple is long.

Comment: Wow... wouldn't have thought. For others who are also surprised note that if `b =  ((1, 2,3), (4, 5), (5,6,7,8))` then `sum(b)` is `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8)`.... and if `c = [(1, 2,3), (4, 5), (5,6,7,8)]` then `sum(c)` is `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8)`. I think that this is just extremely useful to know!

Comment: This only works for tuples that have summable data types.

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a chance `tupleOfTuples` doesn't contain all tuples :)

Answer (score 13):

You're chaining the tuples together:

```
from itertools import chain
print list(chain(*listOfTuples))
```

Should be pretty readable if you're familiar with `itertools`, and without the explicit `list` you even have your result in generator form.

Answer (score 9):

I like using 'reduce' in this situation (this is what reduce made for!)

```
lot = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5,))
print list(reduce(lambda t1, t2: t1 + t2, lot))

 > [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: In before Alex votes you down with his hatred-for-map/reduce-wrath

Comment: Interested in knowing how this compares (in efficiency) with a python list comprehension for large lists

Answer (score 9):

Most of these answers will only work for a single level of flattening.  For a more comprehensive solution, try this (from http://rightfootin.blogspot.com/2006/09/more-on-python-flatten.html):

```
def flatten(l, ltypes=(list, tuple)):
    ltype = type(l)
    l = list(l)
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
        while isinstance(l[i], ltypes):
            if not l[i]:
                l.pop(i)
                i -= 1
                break
            else:
                l[i:i + 1] = l[i]
        i += 1
    return ltype(l)
```

Comment: worked for me to flatten a Tree data structure, where the other solutions didn't go deep enough!

Comment: I like this solution - I prefer a general solutions to a specific one.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
>>> tupleOfTuples = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5,))
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [x for x in chain.from_iterable(tupleOfTuples)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

For multilevel, and readable code:

```
def flatten(bla):
    output = []
    for item in bla:
        output += flatten(item) if hasattr (item, "__iter__") or hasattr (item, "__len__") else [item]
    return output
```

I could not get this to fit in one line (and remain readable, even by far)

Comment: Some code just wasn't meant to be in one line.

Comment: Very helpful for list with varying depth.

Comment: isinstance(item, tuple) instead of hasattr (item, "__iter__") or hasattr (item, "__len__") would make it shorter

Comment: Yes, but then it would work only for tuples - the expression above works for any iterable element in the list - including generators.