# Python: Intertwining two lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

What is the pythonic way of doing the following:

I have two lists `a` and `b` of the same length `n`, and I want to form the list

```
c = [a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1], ..., a[n-1], b[n-1]]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
c = [item for pair in zip(a, b) for item in pair]
```

Read documentation about [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

---

For comparison with Ignacio's answer see this question: [How do I convert a tuple of tuples to a one-dimensional list using list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204245/how-do-i-convert-a-tuple-of-tuples-to-a-one-dimensional-list-using-list-comprehen)

Answer (score 10):

```
c = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(a, b)))
```

Answer (score 7):

```
c = [item for t in zip(a,b) for item in t]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c = [item for i in zip(a,b) for item in i]
```

Alternatively you could try:

```
c=[(a,b)[i%2][i/2] for i in xrange(2*n)]
```

which is of course less readable

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
sum(([x,y] for (x,y) in zip(a,b)), [])
```

(Maybe not very efficient since you form both temporary tuples (x,y) and temporary lists [x,y].)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one (tested on Python 2 and 3):

```
list(sum(zip(a, b), ()))
```

or in numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.vstack((a, b)).T.flatten().tolist()
```