# python: flat zip

Tags: python

I have

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

where `a` has one more element.
`zip(a,b)` returns `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]`. However, I want

```
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']
```

What is the most elegant way?

Comment: I use now `sum(zip(a, b), ())`. It returns a flat tuple. It is a modification of this controverse  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/11769765).

Comment: Mapping the `+` operator to all elements, I come across [reduce](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#reduce), thus `reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, zip(a,b))`. But this is also given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/952943/11769765.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Python: Intertwining two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6356041/7851470).

Comment: len_a = len(list_a) ; 
result = [  list_a[ii//2]   if ii%2==0 else list_b[ii//2]    for ii in range(2*len_a) ]

Answer (score 6):

`itertools` has a function for this.

```py
from itertools import chain

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
result = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehensions, one can use the following:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
result = [item for sublist in zip(a, b) for item in sublist]
# result is [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']
```

This uses the list-flattening comprehension in https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/5666087.

Comment: but those are two for loops, I think this is not as clean, but might be faster ` xx = []  , _ = [xx.extend([x,y]) for x, y in zip(a,b)]  ` now xx is ` [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']
`

Comment: Maybe, but I would choose clean code over fast code. *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*