# Can you create a list of variables in Python without instantiating the variables?

Tags: python, list, loops, variables

I'm trying to make my code cleaner.

I want to do something like:

```
gesture_sensor_data = [nod_gyro, nod_acc, swipe_left_gyro, swipe_right_acc, etc.]
```

I have this right now:

```
nod_gyro, nod_acc = fill_gyro_and_acc_data(nod_intervals, merge)
swipe_right_gyro, swipe_right_acc = fill_gyro_and_acc_data(swipe_right_intervals, merge)
swipe_left_gyro, swipe_left_acc = fill_gyro_and_acc_data(swipe_left_intervals, merge)
whats_up_gyro, whats_up_acc = fill_gyro_and_acc_data(whats_up_intervals, merge)
```

I want to run a loop through the `gesture_sensor_data`.

Is there a way to do this? Some kind of structure or something?

EDIT: I'll just show my full code in this function for context.

```
def generate_gesture_files(i):
    nod_intervals, swipe_left_intervals, swipe_right_intervals, whats_up_intervals = generate_gesture_intervals(i)

    merge = pandas.read_csv(final_user_study_path + "/P" + str(i) + "/DataCollection/data/merge.csv")
    nod_gyro, nod_acc = fill_gyro_and_acc_data(nod_intervals, merge)
    swipe_right_gyro, swipe_right_acc = fill_gyro_and_acc_data(swipe_right_intervals, merge)
    swipe_left_gyro, swipe_left_acc = fill_gyro_and_acc_data(swipe_left_intervals, merge)
    whats_up_gyro, whats_up_acc = fill_gyro_and_acc_data(whats_up_intervals, merge)
    return nod_gyro, nod_acc, swipe_right_gyro, swipe_right_acc, swipe_left_gyro, swipe_right_acc, whats_up_gyro, whats_up_acc
```

Comment: You could collect all those variables in a `dict`.

Comment: What would the keys be?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach as is; what's the issue with it?

Comment: I'm running the same code in four lines which I could do in a simple for loop.

Comment: You don't need that list.  You can loop over itertools.chan([func1(), func2(), func3()])

Comment: @VinayakKaniyarakkal Do you mind writing an answer explaining that solution? I'm a little confused on how to do it.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 what exactly is that function doing on the dataframe? Stuff that's accessing a dataframe 4 times that differs only between what appears to be a "direction" smells a bit off...

Comment: It is fine as it is, other ways will make it more complicated imo. As @tobias_k said, you can wrap it into a dictionary, or a pandas.Series. --- You might want to take out the `read_csv` and put it into a separated data layer, but that might be overkill for now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
itertools.chain([fill_gyro_and_acc_data(i, merge) for i in [
    nod_intervals, swipe_right_intervals, swipe_left_intervals, whats_up_intervals
])
```

Comment: @dirtysocks45: Is it better now?

Comment: Will that work with the logic I have currently in my code? My fill_gyro_and_acc_data returns two variables.

Comment: @dirtysocks45: It doesn't return 2 variables.  It returns an iterable of length 2.  You are unpacking it.  A function always returns only one object.  We are merging multiple iterables using itertools.chain

Comment: so how do I set my local variables like `nod_gyro` to the values returned by this command?

Comment: nod_gyro, nod_acc, swipe_left_gyro, swipe_right_acc, etc = itertools.chain([...])

Comment: I get the error: `TypeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` when I try `nod_gest.append(generate_gesture_files(i)[0])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156874/discussion-between-vinayak-kaniyarakkal-and-dirtysocks45).

Answer (score 0):

you could change your generate_gesture_intervalsand use partial

```
def generate_gesture_files(i):
  return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, [fill_gyro_and_acc_data(arg, merge) for arg in generate_gesture_intervals(i)])
```

Comment: Another way to flatten the results without reduce https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204245/how-do-i-convert-a-tuple-of-tuples-to-a-one-dimensional-list-using-list-comprehe

Comment: Two antipatterns here: don't use `reduce` to reinvent `sum` and don't use `sum` to flatten lists.