# How do I enumerate a list without parenthesis?

Tags: python, list, enumeration

I have this python code, yet it adds parenthesis to the enumeration.  I don't need the parenthesis, so how do I do this in python?  All I need is just to enumerate the list.  this is what it does is

```
num =[(0, '1'), (1, '7'), (2, '11'), (3, '13')
```

this is my code

```
num =['1', '7', '11', '13']
print (list(enumerate(num,0)))
```

I need this below, but I don't the code.

```
num = [1,'1', 2,'7',3,'11',4,'13']
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"I don't need the parenthesis"*?

Comment: Hi kaya3,  I don't need these parenthesis ( )

Comment: That is sign of tuple

Comment: What is an enumeration in your definition if it is not what you posted?

Comment: yes I don't need the Tuple but how do I change the code to print the new enumerated list without Tuple

Comment: Whats the use case , Do you want to print index, value without parenthesis ?

Comment: Edit your question to include the output you *want* the program to have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a tuple of tuples to a one-dimensional list using list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204245/how-do-i-convert-a-tuple-of-tuples-to-a-one-dimensional-list-using-list-comprehe)

Comment: And BTW you need the parentheses, they are part of the syntax. But I suspect you want to do something you did not tell us about.

Comment: Enumeration adds a count to each quoted number. like this  [1,'1', 2,'7',3,'11',4,'13']

Comment: Your code produces `[(0, '1'), (1, '7'), (2, '11'), (3, '13')]` cant relate to your output

Comment: I know Yugandhar Chaudhari but what code would prevent a tuple and just output an enumerated list with quotes.  I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply run a loop as below:

```py
num =['1', '7', '11', '13']
final_list = list()
for index, i in enumerate(num):
    final_list.extend((index, i))

print(final_list)
[0, '1', 1, '7', 2, '11', 3, '13']
```

Comment: Right on Subhrajyoti Das this answered the quetion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import chain

num =['1', '7', '11', '13']
result = list(chain.from_iterable(enumerate(num)))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[0, '1', 1, '7', 2, '11', 3, '13']
```

Answer (score 1):

From you output you mean `enumerate(num,1)`.

Just another short way.

We can add into a empty list after converting tuple to list. `+` here concats two lists

```
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda acc,x: acc + list(x),enumerate(num,1),[])
```

acc is `[]` is empty list initially and adding like `['hello'] + [1,2] = ['hello',1,2]`

**Output**

```
[1, '1', 2, '7', 3, '11', 4, '13']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to Yugandhar Chaudhari answer.

I use `map(list, ...)` to convert tuples to lists and then I can add all lists to empty list `[]` using `sum()` instead of `+` and `reduce()`

```
num = ['1', '7', '11', '13']

print(sum(map(list, enumerate(num, 1)), []))
```