# Find closest RGB color for every pixel in image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm using NumPy to do some image processing. I load an image into an array and get the "nearest" color for each pixel, as follows:

```py
# rgbValues is a global list with 22 RGB values

def getNearestColor(rgb):
    a = []
    for i in range(len(rgbValues)):
        d = ((rgbValues[i][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2
        a.append(d)
    list.sort(a)
    return a[0]

im = np.asarray(Image.open('image.jpg'))

for x in range(len(im)):
    for y in range(len(im[x])):
        for _ in range(len(im[x][y])):
            out[x][y] = getNearestColor(im[x][y])
```

How can I get the actual RGB values in `out`, rather than the distances? How can I improve the performance of the code?

Comment: Are you sure `for i in range(len(im[x][y])):` is there? `i` is not used.

Comment: Changed it... Better? ;)

Comment: In your `getNearestColor` you sort again after each append. But you only have to sort one time, after you end that loop. Then again ... you don't have to maintain a list *at all* – you only want the closest color.

Comment: @hallowed your innermost for-loop doesn't do anything. It just repeats the exact same operation `len(im[x][y])` times.

Comment: I actually only sort once. Formatted that wrong here. Want to you mean with "you don't need to maintain a list"?

Comment: oops, youre right @Heike. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a list because you only want the nearest value. Initially, it's the distance to the first color. Then test the other colors, updating single variables `nearestColorDistance` and `nearestColorIndex` if closer. The result should be `nearestColorIndex` -- not `nearestColorDistance`, which you return now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (corrected) function is:

```
def findNearest(rgb):
    a = []
    for i in range(len(rgbValues)):
        d = ((rgbValues[i][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2
        a.append([d,i])
    list.sort(a)
    return rgbValues[a[0][1]]
```

It returns the correct `rgbValues`; this is now possible because its index get stored in `a` as well. This – in an admittedly roughly timed framework – processes some 27,085 pixels per second.

A straightforward implementation, adjusted to remember only the nearest index:

```
def findNearest(rgb):
    dist = ((rgbValues[0][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[0][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[0][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2
    index = 0
    for i in range(1,len(rgbValues)):
        d = ((rgbValues[i][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2
        if d < dist:
            dist = d
            index = i
    return rgbValues[index]
```

already performs much better: 37,175 pixels per second, a speed improvement of 37%. Can we do better with a more Pythonic approach?

```
def findNearest(rgb):
    dist = [(((rgbValues[i][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2,i) for i in range(22)]
    return rgbValues[min(dist)[1]]
```

Nope. With the same image and the same timing mechanism it goes down to 33,417 pixels/sec.

---

Complete test program, using a random image from an earlier question (it uses PIL to load, access pixels, and display the image, but that is not relevant for the distance calculations):

```
import random
from PIL import Image
from time import time

def findNearest_org(rgb):
    a = []
    for i in range(len(rgbValues)):
        d = ((rgbValues[i][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2
        a.append([d,i])
    list.sort(a)
    return rgbValues[a[0][1]]

def findNearest_raw(rgb):
    dist = ((rgbValues[0][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[0][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[0][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2
    index = 0
    for i in range(1,len(rgbValues)):
        d = ((rgbValues[i][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2
        if d < dist:
            dist = d
            index = i
    return rgbValues[index]

def findNearest_list(rgb):
    dist = [(((rgbValues[i][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2,i) for i in range(22)]
    return rgbValues[min(dist)[1]]

image = Image.open('output-2.png')
pixels = image.load()
width, height = image.size

rgbValues = [tuple(random.randrange(0,256) for _ in range(3)) for _ in range(22)]

start = time()
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        # fetch the rgb value
        color = pixels[x,y]
        # replace with nearest
        pixels[x,y] = findNearest_list (color)
print ('pixels/sec:', (width*height)/(time()-start))

image.show()
```

and test images before and after:

[image: test image before]

[image: test image after]

If you are only interested in results, use whatever native method your image library allows. This short piece using PIL's own [`quantize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.quantize)

```
rgbValues = list(sum(rgbValues, ()))*12
rgbValues = rgbValues[:768]
palimage = Image.new('P', (width, height))
palimage.putpalette(rgbValues)
newimage = image.quantize(palette=palimage)
```

outsources the calculations to native code, and the results are quite staggeringly better: 18,443,414 pixels/sec – a whopping *500 times faster* than my native (/naïve) implementation.
(Hyper-fancy tuple-to-list comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3205524)

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks a lot! I'm obviously using the PIL implementation. But since I'm learning to program your answer was awesome to understand the concept behind it.
But why is their method so much better/faster?

Comment: @hallowed: large parts of PIL are [written in C](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/tree/master/src) and are thus compiled to native executable code on your machine. Even a naive implementation in C will outperform anything in Python in this. (Disclaimer: you may notice I did not test with NumPy. It might do better than my own, but you have to read and write pixels using Python, so it's *likely* still not as fast as PIL.)

Comment: Could you explain what you did for the PIL implementation? What does this do `rgbValues = list(sum(rgbValues, ()))*12

rgbValues = rgbValues[:768]`

the palette sequence must contain 768 integer values, this is somehow doing that (I would assume) but what is actually happening?

Comment: Your 22 colors are not enough to fill an entire array of 3*256 values. You can't pad it with 0's because then the palette would contain a 23rd color. So this copies the list 12 times -> 264 RGB triples. That's too much so [a slice action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) cuts it down again. (Any further questions are best asked a-new, lest we'd be accused of "chat"...)