# Unpack tuples inside a tuple

Tags: python, tuples, unpack

For the following:

```
tup = ((element1, element2),(value1, value2))
```

I have used:

```
part1, part2 = tup
tup_to_list = [*part1, *part2]
```

Is there a cleaner way to do so? Is there "double unpacking"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to flatten a general tuple of tuples, you could:

1. use a list/generator comprehension

```py
flattened_tup = tuple(j for i in tup for j in i)
```

2. use itertools

```py
import itertools
flattened_tup = tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(tup))
```

Comment: Itertools will likely have the better performance here.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 2):

`tup = part1+part2`
python adds the objects of tuples behind each other during addition

Answer (score 0):

If there is no harm in using loops then you could try this

```
[tupl for tuploftupls in tup for tupl in tuploftupls]
```

Here's the same kind of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204245/how-do-i-convert-a-tuple-of-tuples-to-a-one-dimensional-list-using-list-comprehe)

Comment: Using a builtin as a variable name is almost universally a bad idea. Also the variable name `values` is misleading as it is a singular value.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of performance, *if I had to* ***repeatedly*** *perform such concatenations* over small `tup`s, I would go for the builtin function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), providing it with an empty tuple as starting value, i.e. `sum(tup, ())`. Otherwise, I would go for [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)-based solution of @Lucas.

---

Performance comparisons.

***Commonalities***

```
import itertools
import timeit

scripts = {
    'builtin_sum'         : "sum(tup, t0)",
    'chain_from_iterable' : "(*fi(tup),)",
    'nested_comprehension': "[tupl for tuploftupls in tup for tupl in tuploftupls]",
}
env = {
    'fi' : itertools.chain.from_iterable,
    't0' : (),
}
def timer(scripts, env):
    for u, s in scripts.items():
        print(u, f': `{s}`')
        print(f'\t\t{timeit.timeit(s, globals=env):0.4f}s')
```

***Small `tup`***

```
>>> env['tup'] = tuple(2*(0,) for _ in range(4))
>>> timer(scripts, env)
builtin_sum : `sum(tup, t0)`  
        0.2976s
chain_from_iterable : `(*fi(tup),)`  
        0.4653s
nested_comprehension : `[tupl for tuploftupls in tup for tupl in tuploftupls]`
        0.7203s
```

***Not small `tup`***

```
>>> env['tup'] = tuple(10*(0,) for _ in range(50))
>>> timer(scripts, env)
builtin_sum : `sum(tup, t0)`
        63.2285s
chain_from_iterable : `(*fi(tup),)`  
        11.9186s
nested_comprehension : `[tupl for tuploftupls in tup for tupl in tuploftupls]`  
        20.0901s
```